# Networking for collaboration

Tags: edubuntu

Trying to understand what features are there for local n/w in a class where a teacher gets to see on his/her monitor what has been typed by a student as an answer

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use one of these two free programs to control the classroom, receive their answers and more, that you can find directly in the Ubuntu Software Center, if they are not pre-installed:

- [iTalc](http://italc.sourceforge.net/home.php)
- [ControlAula](http://www.itais.net/help/en/)